# From half to double, linear to logarithmic scale.

Tags: calculus, logarithms

I am making a game where you want a skill value to modify some in game values. With a scale that goes from half to double. 50% to 200%. If I'd do it linear 125% will be the centre but I want the centre to be 100%.

I want a mathematical function:

- Where I input and number from 0 to 100.
- And get out a number from 0.5 to 2 or from 50% to 200%.
- The function maps 0 to 0.5.
- The function maps 50 to 1.
- The function maps 100 to 2.
- And I would like it to follow a logarithmic scale.
- I do not care what happens outside the specified range.

I have made [this Google Docs document](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/pub?hl=no&hl=no&key=0AnvYMxpZuRxEdDNVM2c3WDBhTHlPbjh1TUQ3eGJyc0E&output=html) which shows my plan B.

I hope someone out there can help me this has been a mathematical problem that has bugged me for years.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x$ is your input between $0$ and $100$, then $2^{\left(\frac{x}{50}-1\right)}=\exp(\frac{\ln 2}{50}x-1)$ will range from $.5$ to $2$ as specified.

Comment: I'm testing it now.